# Casting JNI Types to C++ Types

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI in my company and need to convert some Java types to the corresponding  C++ types. I was successfully casting a Java String to a C++ array, but now I'm struggling with some other Java.lang types.
I need to convert a Java.lang.Integer and a Java.lang.Boolean to the corresponding C++ types. I adapted the same principles from the String conversion to the Integer conversion but I am only getting some false numbers. FYI: I need to call the variables from separated classes. So the Integer is used in foo.bar.IntField and the Boolean in foo.bar.BooleanField
Here is what I have so far:

```
jclass fieldClass = env->FindClass("foo/bar/IntField");
jmethodID getValue = env->GetMethodID(fieldClass, "getValue", "()Ljava/lang/Integer;");
jint value = (jint)env->CallObjectMethod(fieldObject, getValue);
int val = (int)value;
```

The Problem I have is that I don't get the right numbers from that Method. I should get a 0 but the method returns 267713816. The same goes for the bool value. I should get a false but the method returns true. Also the same wrong values are returned, if the CallInt or CallBooleanMethods are used. 
For Strings, there is a way to get the StringUTFChars. I think that this is a formatting error. I hope my explanation is fine and you can help me.

Edit: As suggested by Tom Blodget I posted my answer as an answer.

Comment: You never check any return values. That makes the code essentially undebuggable.

Comment: I removed the checks from the code to improbe the readability. But I was able to find the problem, see Edit for more information

Comment: Note that `GetStringUTFChars` converts a Unicode/UTF-16 encoded Java string to a 0x00-terminated Unicode/*modified* UTF-8 encoded string. If that's not what you use on the C++ side, use `GetStringChars` (not 0x00-terminated) or call String.getBytes(Charset charset) or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: I need to get the integer from the IntField and on this object I need to call the `intValue` method from the Integer class.

```
jclass integerClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID integerID = env->GetMethodID(integerClass, "intValue", "()I");
jint jintVal = (jint)env->CallIntMethod(value, integerID);
int val = (int)jintVal;
```

The same goes for the Boolean value.

```
jclass BooleanClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Boolean");
jmethodID booleanID = env->GetMethodID(BooleanClass, "booleanValue", "()Z");
jboolean jBoolVal = (jboolean)env->CallBooleanMethod(jBoolean, booleanID);
bool boolVal = (bool)jBoolVal;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Zjava/lang/Boolean`, according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html?